# Use appscript to track user installs of google marketplace app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, urlfetch, google-apps-marketplace

We've developed a Google Marketplace app using AppsScript which we've now made live on the marketplace (https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/report_connector_for_salesforce_beta/977246938879). However, we're struggling to work out how to use the Google Marketplace API (https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/example-calls-marketplace-api) to access the license data. Has anyone else successfully managed this?

Has anyone else managed to get this working? It would be great if there was an app for this by the way on the marketplace!

Many thanks

Andy

So far, we've created a separate Google Sheet (in the same domain as our app), and we've written a simple API call function as follows:

```
function getUsers() {

  const options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    }
  };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://appsmarket.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/<our app Id>",options); 
  Logger.log("Refresh Response:"+response); 
}
```

We've created a new project in the GCP, and have enabled:
Google Workspace Marketplace API
Google Workspace Marketplace SDK

We've added the following scopes to the project:

Connect to an external service  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
View your installed application's licensing information https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license

But, when we run the code, we just keep getting the following:

```
Info    Refresh Response:{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I needed to add "https://*.googleapis.com/" in the `urlFetchWhitelist`.

Is your App Id correct? Check it out at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?project=*projectName*

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the urlFetchWhiteList? Is it in the project?

Comment: In the manifest file appsscript.json for the project.

Comment: Is this script running in another CGP project?

Comment: Yes. It's running in a separate project to that of the application. Is that a problem? I was concerned that I'd break the app if I associated the code with the same project?

Comment: OK. I changed it to the same project as my app is linked to, and it now all works! Many thanks.